# JS merge two subarray using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, sub-array

I use the following to merge two arrays:

```js
var mySeries = [
    { name: '4', data: [4] },
    { name: '3', data: [3] }
];
var mySeries1 = [
    { name: '5', data: [0] },
    {name: '4', data:[0]},
    {name: '3', data:[0]},
    {name: '2', data:[0]},
    { name: '1', data: [0] }
];

var res = mySeries1.map(obj => mySeries.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);
console.log(res);
```

Works great; however, my challenge is my array is structured as:

```
var myArray = [{ 
    mySeries : [
        { name: '4', data: [4] },
        { name: '3', data: [3] }],
    mySeries1 : [
        { name: '5', data: [0] },
        { name: '4', data: [0] },
        { name: '3', data: [0] },
        { name: '2', data: [0] },
        { name: '1', data: [0] }]
    }];
];
```

So I need to map subarrays, tried using the following:

```
var res = myArray.mySeries1.map(obj => myArray.mySeries.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

How can I point to the subarray?

Comment: [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: `myArray` is an array, not an object. There's no `myArray.mySeries`. It's `myArray[0].mySeries`

Comment: You are trying to ready `myArray.mySeries1`, but myArray is an array, so you can't access it like that, you should do `myArray[0].myseries1.map()` . But why are you using an array to hold only one value. Are you going to have multiple objects and you have to merge all of them ?

Comment: What is your expected output? why not just use spread operator?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar How would spread operator help?

Comment: @Barmar Is he not trying to merge two arrays? like  `[...mySeries, ...mySeries1]` ? or the expected out is different? this is why I was asking what is the expected output.

Comment: Actually, what he's doing is *replacing* the elements in `mySeries1` with their corresponding element in `mySeries`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myArray = [{ 
    mySeries : [
        { name: '4', data: [4] },
        { name: '3', data: [3] }],
        mySeries1 : [
            { name: '5', data: [0] },
            { name: '4', data: [0] },
            { name: '3', data: [0] },
            { name: '2', data: [0] },
            { name: '1', data: [0] }
        ]
        }];

var res = myArray[0].mySeries1.map(obj => myArray[0].mySeries.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: can I use  var res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){ 
 var res = result[i].mySeries1.map(obj => result[i].mySeries.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);  if I have multiple arrays?  Thanks
 }

Answer (score 0):

you could change your array to dictionary and iterate it like you already did.

```js
var myArray = { 
    mySeries : [
        { name: '4', data: [4] },
        { name: '3', data: [3] }],
    mySeries1 : [
        { name: '5', data: [0] },
        { name: '4', data: [0] },
        { name: '3', data: [0] },
        { name: '2', data: [0] },
        { name: '1', data: [0] }]
    };
```

i.e. `var res = myArray.mySeries1.map(obj => myArray.mySeries.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);`